# exclude member while using Fetch in Petapoco

Tags: petapoco

Thinking of trying to use Petapoco.Fetch where member "content" is an c# object.

"Content" member is byte[] member which I store in cache og want to retrieve specially .. not from database.

So:

```
SQL = "select * table.FundDocument";

List<FundDocument> fundDocuments = new List<FundDocument>();
fundDocuments = database.Fetch<FundDocument>(SQL)
                .IgnoreORExcept(FundDocument.content = GetDocumentFromCache(id));
```

So petapoco object would fetch everything except the member "content", it would fetch that from the function GetDocumentFromCache();

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ExplicitColumns` in your POCO and exclude the property from being retrieved or you can name it different, so PetaPoco don't retrieve it.